# How to load 2nd modified file in folder

Tags: python

I have to create a automated script in which I have to make sure that the 2nd modified/updated file needs to be picked as a data frame in Python.

Eg: Suppose I have a folder Test and in that I have 2 file 2022-03-24.csv and 2022-03-23.csv so when I run my Python script system should automatically run 2022-03-23.csv file since it's updated or created on 23rd March.

Below is the code which I am using but this code is used to load most recent data i.e. 2022-03-24.csv file

```
import glob
import os.path
import pandas as pd

folder_path = r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test'
file_type = r'\*csv'
files = glob.glob(folder_path + file_type)
max_file = max(files, key=os.path.getctime)

import_file = pd.read_csv(max_file)
print(import_file)
```

I want to load 2nd modified data i.e. 2022-03-23.csv

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: If you want to read multiple files, how about **sorting** `files` list instead of using `max`?

Comment: I have tried with sorted() function but there is one issue.  At the end of the day new data is dumped so tomorrow I will have 3 file 2022-03-25.csv, 2022-03-24.csv, 2022-03-23.csv and if I use sorted() function it will load 2022-03-23.csv and tomorrow I have to load 2022-03-24.csv file.

Comment: Thanks it worked I have made my index value to -2 so after sorting it will pick the 2nd file daily